# Starting emulator for AVD Nokia

Tags: android, nokiax

I am trying to start emulator for Nokia x os but it fail and showing error like

"Starting emulator for AVD 'Nokia'
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!"

while creating it shows warning

[image]
My Sdk is showing that image is installed but still Emulator is not starting!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your first screenshot there seems to be a warning that says *The AVD may not work correctly unless you install the armeabi-v7a system image for Android 4.1.2 (API 16) first* (If I read that correctly), and your error seems to verify that it is not installed. Yet your second screenshot lists the image as installed.

Are you sure you do not have two Android SDK's installed and the AVD manager is using the other one (that does not have armeabi installed) and your SDK manager uses the other one? Android Studio for example comes bundled with the Android SDK.

Make sure you have environment variable ANDROID_HOME set and pointing to your *SDK* directory:

```
C:\>echo %ANDROID_HOME%
C:\Applications\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk
```

Try to locate your Android SDK and run the SDK manager and AVD manager from the same SDK. You seem to be running Windows, so you should execute *AVD Manager.exe* and *SDK Manager.exe* from the SDK home directory.

If you only have one SDK installed, the installation might be corrupted. Try to uninstall/reinstall *ARM EABI v7a System image for API level 16* and delete the AVD and create it again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running on an Intel based development machine, you should select the Intel ABI rather than the Arm one.

Comment: I have tried for both Intel and arm , but same warning and error message when creating and starting

Comment: Do other targets work, i.e. is it just Nokia X specific issue ? if it is, then can you remove the parts, and try re-installation using the Add-on site with Android SDK manager